# Add a Line Break In HTML Email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-email

I have made a request form for my work and it working as expected. I have placed some text in the text area as a hide/show for users. On the visual studio code, I see the line breaks fine but when I submit the form and the recipient gets the email all that was in the text area is all in one line instead of line break where I wanted.

Also how to kill the extra white spaces. Also have used this

Is there any fix to this?

I get this in email `DC GM Groups  Domain Group Access:  All Folders and Drives Required Distribution List:  All Emails`

Tried everything I could research but doesn't seem to work

```css
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: left;
width: 650px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <!-- style="visibility:hidden;" -->
  <!-- acc means account -->
  <textarea class="textarea" id="acc_GMGroup" name="acc_GMGroup" rows="10">
Domain Group Access:&#13;&#10;&emsp;All Folders and Drives Required&#13;&#10;
Distribution List:&#13;&#10;&emsp;All Emails

                            </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but when i type<br> or<p> but it includes <br><p> thinking as text

Comment: literally hard-code it instead of en-code it.

Comment: You don't show us the form action, so it's difficult to answer specifically, but it seems as if you're sending plain text (the content of `textarea`) while the email header is probably saying the content is HTML. So the email client will parse it as HTML, which ignores whitespace. Look into TinyMCE, which will convert your `textarea` into a rich-text editor and can output HTML. OR, send the emails as *plain text* **not** HTML.

Comment: My form has over 20000 lines

Comment: In other words, check for `Content-Type: text/html;` in your email's header. If that can change to `Content-Type: text/plain;` then it'll probably be sorted.

Comment: What email client are you testing this in?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first two questions

The easiest way to format like it is in the text area is to put the text between `<pre>...</pre>` tags

The other thing you could do is use regular expressions to switch from text to html, like

```
text.replace(/[\n]/g,"<br>");
text.replace(/\s\s+/g,function(part) {
  return part.substring(0,1);
}));
```

Comment: Appending `<pre>` to the start and end of the textarea sounds like an excellent quick hack to getting the email showing correctly!

Comment: <code><pre></code> doesnt work

Comment: Tried everything but doest do the trick to add a line break to the text togo on next line as in textarea

Answer (score 0):

A `textarea` will render whitespace as it was entered into the element so just format the whitespace by literally adding it.

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <textarea class="textarea" id="acc_GMGroup" name="acc_GMGroup" rows="10">
Domain Group Access:
 All Folders and Drives Required
 
Distribution List:
 All Emails
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to do deep research and found you can do this to make it work: just add nl2br

`$usersGMGroup = nl2br($_POST["acc_GMGroup"]);`

Thank you to all the people that helped to resolve the issue